# Symfony forward with @Template

Tags: symfony

I have an entry point controller (editAction) which depending on a route variable ({property}) will display different templates. I am using annotation "@Template".

I tried a lots of differtings settings but none is working. The closing that I got is with the following :

Error is " The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes "

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $property, $id)
{
    // controller logic

    $form = $this->createForm('ObjectEdit'.ucfirst($property), $object);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();



        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme-demo-dashboard-show'));
        }

    $response = $this->forward('AcmeDemoBundle:Dashboard:edit'. ucfirst($property),
                                array('form' => $form)
                                );


    return $response;
}

/**
 * Edit Title property for Object
 * @Template
 */
public function editTitleAction($form)
{
    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Yaml Routing:

```
acme-demo-dashboard-edit:
    path:  /dashboard/edit/{property}/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Dashboard:edit }
    requirements:

acme-demo-dashboard-edit-title:
    path:  /dashboard/forward/edit/title/{form}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Dashboard:editTitle }
```

Edit: More info about the error :

```
at twig_array_merge (null, array('_locale' => 'en'))
```

Edit2: Twig Template for editTitle

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain "AcmeDemoBundle" %}

{% block AcmeBundleContent %}
<div class="col-sm-12">

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                                {{ (ycRoute~'.intro') | trans }}
                </div>

                {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form'}}) }}

                {% if form_errors(form) %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                {{ form_errors(form) }}
                                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="form-group {% if form_errors(form.title) %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                {{ form_label(form.title, '', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                {{ form_widget(form.title, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': (ycRoute~'.titre') } }) }}
                                                <p class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.title) }}</p> 
                                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'} }) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            (<i class="fa fa-asterisk yc-fa-sm"></i>) {{ (ycRoute~'.champRequis')|trans }}
        </div>
    </div>

                {{ form_end(form)}}

</div>
{% endblock AcmeBundleContent %}
```

Comment: Please post the twig template for the edit action.

Comment: I have posted the Twig template which only renders the form :)

Comment: OK, so the reason I asked for the template is because it looks like the problem is somewhere you are trying to merge null with an array, and twig doesn't like that.  I don't see any merge filter being used in the template, so perhaps it's in layout.html.twig?

Comment: Hello, your comment led me on good direction :) It was indeed a merge problems which comes from _route and _route_params disappearing when forwarding. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5804

Answer (score 0):

Did you try such syntax to render template? You will need remove @Template annotation.

```
 return $this->render(
            'AcmeDemoBundle:Dashboard:edit'. ucfirst($property),
             array('form' => $form)
        );
```

"forward" used for forwards the request to another controller.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, however I encouter the exact same error with this method.